# What's the easiest way to block my web app from public view, but open to the developer only?

Tags: google-cloud-run

I've got an app on Cloud Run that I'm using as a utility tool. Right now I can only see the UI if I set `allUsers` to `Cloud Run Invoker` role, but I want to do the opposite, block allUsers EXCEPT myself from viewing the UI of the deployed app on the web. What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: To clarify what you mean by UI, you want to use this service from a web browser where only you have access?

Comment: Hi @Grayside, yes exactly, from a web browser.

Comment: Due to lack of IAP, you can try to integrate with Firebase Auth, or "Sign in with Google", but that would introduce extra coding work as you might imagine.

Answer (score 3):

There is no easy way to do this with Cloud Run. Until now (and I hope that will change soon) Cloud Run is not a web frontend like AppEngine and it's not protected by [IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/).

By the way, the easiest way is to deploy your utility tool on AppEngine and then to activate IAP. If your utility tool is not compliant with AppEngine standard, you can use AppEngine Flex which deploy a container (use [custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/)). But you can't scale to 0, there is a cost impact.